# How can I copy files across directories in Erlang?

Tags: file, erlang, copy

This works:

```
1> file:copy(test.html, test1.html).
{ok,2384}
```

But this doesn't:

```
2> file:copy(test.html, sites/test.html). 
   ** exception error: bad argument in an arithmetic expression
   in operator  '/'/2
   called as sites / 'test.html'
```

How can I copy files across directories in Erlang?

Many thanks,

LRP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some big files cause problems when you copy/move them within erlang. It is sometimes safer to use `os:cmd/1`. like this:

```
move(Source, Destination)->
    %% For Windows
    Command = "MOVE \"" ++ Source ++ "\" \"" ++ Destination ++ "\"",
    %% For Unix/Linux
    %%Command = "mv \"" ++ Source ++ "\" \"" ++ Destination ++ "\"",
    spawn(os,cmd,[Command]).

copy(Source, Destination)->
    %% For Windows
    Command = "XCOPY \"" ++ Source ++ "\" \"" ++ Destination ++ "\"",
    %% For Unix/Linux
    %%Command = "cp \"" ++ Source ++ "\" \"" ++ Destination ++ "\"",
    spawn(os,cmd,[Command]).
```

Comment: take not that the `Source` and `Destination` variables may contain either `forward slash` or `back slash` depending on whether the system is running windows or unix-linux

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that `sites/test.html` has special characters and has to be inside single quotes. Try:

```
file:copy(test.html, 'sites/test.html').
```

Or you can use strings:

```
file:copy("test.html", "sites/test.html").
```